# Printing html like contents form a textarea using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

We can get the text inside a tag using the get_text() function in BeautifulSoup. But what if the text area contains some html like code.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<html><h1>#include <stdio.h></h1></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
print soup.h1.get_text()
```

The above program prints "#include" but I wanted it to be full text inside h1.
This is just a small example. I am working with with scraping a c++ code from web. I have navigated to the text area in which code is present but when I print it it doesn't print the header files.
Textarea:

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" data-input-file="1">#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct points
{
    int x;
    int count;
};
points a[105];
int main()
{
    int n;
    int k;
    int t;
    int i;
    int j;

    scanf("%d",&t);

    while(t--) {
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
        for(i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            scanf("%d",&a[i].x);
            a[i].count = 1;
            if(a[i].x == -1) {
                a[i].x = 1000000000;
            }
        }

        for(i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                if((a[i-j].x + a[j].x) < a[i].x && (a[i-j].count + a[j].count) <= n) {
                    a[i].x = a[i-j].x + a[j].x;
                    a[i].count = a[i-j].count + a[j].count;
                }
            }
        }

        if(a[k].x == 1000000000) {
            printf("-1\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%d\n",a[k].x);
        }
    }



}
</textarea>
```

My code for scraping:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(parser = "lxml")
browser.open('http://www.spoj.com/')
form = browser.get_form(id='login-form')
form['login_user'].value = username
form['password'].value = password
browser.submit_form(form)
browser.open('http://www.spoj.com/myaccount')
l = browser.find(id = "user-profile-tables").find_all('td')
link = l[0].a['href']
link = "http://www.spoj.com" + link
browser.open(link)
codelink = browser.find(title = 'Edit source code')['href']
codelang = browser.find(class_ = 'slang text-center').get_text()
codelink = "http://www.spoj.com" + codelink
browser.open(codelink)
print browser.find(id = 'submit_form').textarea.get_text()
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lt and gt signs should be escaped like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<html><h1>#include  &lt;stdio.h&gt;</h1></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
print(soup.h1.get_text())
```

Which would then give you:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
```

None of the parsers are going to consider that text unless they are escaped. each one will give you `#include  <stdio.h></stdio.h>`

You may just have to resort to a regex to extract the include statements from the source itself.

```
 patt = re.compile(r"<h1>(\s+)?(#include\s+.*?)(\s+)?</h1>")
```

Comment: I am scraping a C code from the web and what I get is a code without header files. I dont think I can accomplish your idea with it since I don't have the code at my hand.

Comment: @ShivamMitra, can you share a sample url? If it shows in the browser then it should be escaped or all you would see is the #include

Comment: So the code is not in a `code` block? can you actually provide a link that has the same format or do you have to log in?

Comment: I have to log in for that.

Comment: I don't see any way to do it with bs4, the <> are going to mean it is treated as a tag, really if you see it in your browser I cannot see how it is not escaped. I added a regex approach which I think is about your only option